# Bold key words within an unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Please see relevant jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/feh9ngva/)

I have a list here where I want to make every word that says 'Bold' bold.

```
<ul id = "list">
    <li>Make this word Bold</li>
    <li>Bold this as well</li>
<ul>
```

JS:

```
$('#list li').each(function () {
                var text = $(this).text();
                var value = 'bold';
     
                if (text.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1) {
                    var html = $(this).html();
                    $(this).html(html.replace(value, "<span id='highlight' style='font-weight: bold'>" + value + "</span>"));
                }

            });
```

So the output would be:

> Make this word **Bold**
>
> **Bold** this as well

How can I fix my code?

Comment: Should it keep the initial case? If not, this works:  http://jsfiddle.net/axre34my/

Comment: It should but thanks for the fiddle

Comment: @blex What if I want the regex to contain a variable like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/axre34my/2/

Comment: I changed my answer to avoid some bugs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Regex, you can select `bold`, (multiple occurrences, using the `g` option, and not case-sensitive, using `i`). Then, use parenthesis to *capture* the original word, and reuse it by using `$1`:

```
var regex = new RegExp("(" + value + ")", "gi");
$(this).html( $(this).html().replace(regex, "<b>$1</b>") );
```

But replacing `.html()` might cause interesting stuff to happen if the keyword is present in the markup, i.e:

```
<span style="font-weight:<b>bold</b>"></span>
```

```js
$('#list li').each(function() {
  
  var text = $(this).text();
  var value = 'bold';
  var regex = new RegExp("(" + value + ")", "gi");

  if (text.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1) {
    $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(regex, "<b>$1</b>") );
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="list">
  <li>Make this word Bold</li>
  <li>Bold this as well</li>
  <li>BOLD, bOld and bold also get BOld!</li>
  <li><span style="font-weight:bold">This whole sentence is <b>NOT</b> bold because the style attribute was modified. Doh!</span></li>
</ul>
```

To avoid that, a more accurate version of the regex would be to check whether the keyword is enclosed with `<>`:

```
var regex = new RegExp("(" + value + ")(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*<\/)", "gi");
```

### Demo

```js
$('#list li').each(function() {
  
  var text = $(this).text();
  var value = 'bold';
  var regex = new RegExp("(" + value + ")(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*<\/)", "gi");

  if (text.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1) {
    $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(regex, "<b>$1</b>") );
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="list">
  <li>Make this word Bold</li>
  <li>Bold this as well</li>
  <li>BOLD, bOld and bold also get BOld!</li>
  <li><span style="font-weight:bold">This whole sentence is bold because the style attribute was not modified. Yay!</span></li>
</ul>
```